# Does order matter when dealing with quantifiers?

Tags: notation

Do ${\forall}x{\forall}y{\exists}z$, ${\forall}x({\forall}y{\exists}z)$ and $({\forall}x{\forall}y){\exists}z$ all mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but there is a difference between $\forall x (\forall y A\wedge B)$ and $(\forall x \forall y) (A\wedge B)$ but that's probably clear.

Comment: Why would it be clear?

Comment: Consider these formulas concerning real numbers: (1) $\forall x ((\forall y \,\,x>y) \vee (y=0))$, and (2) $(\forall x \forall y) ((x>y) \vee (y=0))$. The second one has no free variables and is false: the first has a free variable $y$ and is true/false depending on $y$.

Comment: Yes, order matters A LOT. Try to read some book of logic, order is essential in quantifiers.

Comment: @Masacroso It's confusing but he doesn't really ask about order, but about parenthesis. The way he wrote it, it looks like being the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but the second two are confusing. The analogy with an operation like $+$ is misleading. You always just take the quantifiers in the order they are given. The parentheses make people wonder what is going on.